# inserting large amount of data into bigquery via node

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

How are you doing.

I need some help.

I created a node application to take data from MongoDB and insert this record into the BigQuery table.

I store all records from the Mongo collection into a variable and after that I call another function to send these records into BigQuery.

If I filter my variable before send I don't have any problem.
If a try to send a large amount of record I got this error:
Error inserting rows: Error: Multiple errors occurred during the request. Please see the `errors` array for complete details.
1. Request Entity Too Large
So I re-wrote my code:

```
    const batchSize = 500;
    const numBatches = Math.ceil(dataMongo.length / batchSize);
    let numInserted = 0;
    const failedIds = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < numBatches; i++) {
      const start = i * batchSize;
      const end = start + batchSize;
      const batch = dataMongo.slice(start, end);
  
      try {
        const [apiResponse] = await table.insert(batch);
        numInserted += apiResponse.insertErrors ? apiResponse.insertErrors.length : batch.length;
        console.log(`Inserted ${numInserted} rows into ${dataset.id}.${table.id}`);
      } catch (err) {
        // An API error or partial failure occurred.
  
        if (err.name === 'PartialFailureError') {
          console.log('Some rows failed to insert, while others may have succeeded.');
  
          // Log the errors for the failed rows.
          err.errors.forEach((error) => {
            console.log(`Error inserting row: ${JSON.stringify(error.row)}. Reason: ${error.errors[0].reason}. Message: ${error.errors[0].message}`);
            // Add the failed _id to the array.
            failedIds.push(error.row._id);
          });
        } else {
          console.log(`Error inserting rows: ${err}`);
        }
      }
    }
```

But in this way all record are reject, telling me that some fields are missing in the BigQuery. But I am sure I have all fields.

If I loop through my variable I am able to insert the record.

Does anyone know how to fix it? or How is the best way to insert a large amount of data into BigQuery after getting these recordo from MongoDB?

Comment: Hi there can you please also edit your post above and put in the table insert function that writes to bigquery? if possible also paste the bigquery table schema

Comment: You also have a 1 record overlap when you do the insert.  Iteration goes from 0-500, 500-1000, 1000-1500, etc.